# Exhausted messages in Spring XD with RabbitMQ as the message bus

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring XD 1.2.0 installation with one server and a couple of containers using RabbitMQ as the message bus and I see lots of WARN messages in the logs such as these ones:

`2017-02-05T22:51:03+0100 1.2.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries  exhausted for message (Body:'Sent RUNNING to notification URL: http://doopex-back2:5002/services/data-project/project/5745722984ae22d0317b6377/http/5745743700b0b2c 10ca5494d/execution?action=RUNNING'MessageProperties [headers={contentType=text/plain}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, ty pe=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, expiration=null, priority=0, redeliver ed=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1, deliveryTag=14, messageCount=0])
2017-02-05T22:52:03+0100 1.2.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries  exhausted for message (Body:'Sent RUNNING to notification URL: http://doopex-back2:5002/services/data-project/project/5745722984ae22d0317b6377/http/5745743700b0b2c 10ca5494d/execution?action=RUNNING'MessageProperties [headers={contentType=text/plain}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, ty pe=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, expiration=null, priority=0, redeliver ed=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1, deliveryTag=15, messageCount=0])
2017-02-05T22:53:03+0100 1.2.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries  exhausted for message (Body:'Sent RUNNING to notification URL: http://doopex-back2:5002/services/data-project/project/5745722984ae22d0317b6377/http/5745743700b0b2c 10ca5494d/execution?action=RUNNING'MessageProperties [headers={contentType=text/plain}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, ty pe=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, expiration=null, priority=0, redeliver ed=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1, deliveryTag=16, messageCount=0])
2017-02-05T22:54:03+0100 1.2.0.RELEASE WARN xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1-1 retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer - Retries  exhausted for message (Body:'Sent RUNNING to notification URL: http://doopex-back2:5002/services/data-project/project/5745722984ae22d0317b6377/http/5745743700b0b2c 10ca5494d/execution?action=RUNNING'MessageProperties [headers={contentType=text/plain}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, ty pe=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=null, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=null, expiration=null, priority=0, redeliver ed=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=xdbus.s5745722984ae22d0317b6377-8ef5f339-f901-4c95-ae11-111be263ce82.1, deliveryTag=17, messageCount=0])`

I'm not quite sure what's going on, but could someone let me know whether I should worry about this? Is this an issue with RabbitMQ or Spring XD itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means one of your modules is failing to process a message - you should see additional information (stack trace) in the log.

You certainly do with the current version (1.3.1); I have a vague memory that old versions didn't log the stack trace, which provides the reason for the failure.

Comment: Gary, is 1.3.1 compatible with 1.2.0? Is it just about upgrading to 1.3.1 and re-starting? Thanks.

Comment: I believe so, yes.